# heroku run mix command not found

Tags: heroku, deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

while deploying a Phoenix project, on Heroku it is saying mix command not found

I checked the Buildpacks of elixir and Phoenix are installed, pushed the code also before running the task.

tried after doing changes in the bashrc file (commented the code for "if not running interactively, don't do anything")

also tried with a change in the `.profile` file (`$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh`)

although `"mix phoenix.server"` is working fine

```
heroku run 'POOL_SIZE=2 mix test.task'
```

> Running POOL_SIZE=2 mix test.task on ⬢ evening-hollows-99899... up, run.2532 (Free)
>   bash: mix: command not found

Comment: Which buildpacks are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static

Comment: Did you try connect to a dyno via SSH and see if mix is there? It might be only a problem with path when running it.